# Why is the interior of $\{(x_n)_n \in {\displaystyle \ell ^{2}}| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2|x_n|^2 < \infty\}$ empty?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M=\{(x_n)_n \in {\displaystyle \ell ^{2}}| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2|x_n|^2 < \infty\}$. How can I show that the interior of M is empty?

I already showed that M is convex but I'm not sure if that's helping.

Comment: What is $\ell$?

Comment: I would assume its the space of square summable sequences in R, right?

Comment: Usually written $l_2$.

Comment: Yes, I meant the space of square summable sequences in R.

Comment: It's better than a convex subset. It is a closed subspace .. can it have non empty interior?

Comment: @r9m: Nice approach..

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Let $y_n = {1 \over n}$, note that $y \in l_2$, but $y \notin M$.

Suppose $x \in M$. Look at $x+ty$ for small $t$.